# Numerical Integration of $g(x)=4\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

The limits of integration are $[0,1]$ and thus the result should be $\pi$. My book suggests an elegant way to evaluate the integral by Monte Carlo Integration but I was wondering, can we reach the same result with an easier way? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try something as x = Sin[y] ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\sin u:= x\implies du\cos u=dx\implies$$

$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=\int \cos^2u\,du=\frac{u+\sin u\cos u}2\;\ldots$$

Comment: That works! Thank you.